# Can the aliases.js File Return an Object in load-grunt-config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

In the `load-grunt-config` module, we add an `aliases.js` file to use aliases, which are usually created with `grunt.registerTask(alias, [task_array]);` in the `Gruntfile` when not using `load-grunt-config`. Is there a way to have this `aliases.js` file return a nested object, instead of simply a string consisting of all the aliases?

I would like my `aliases.js` file to be something like this:

```
module.exports = {

    scss: {

        scss: 'sass',

    }
};
```

but when I try to run `scss`, `grunt` gives:

```
$ grunt scss
Warning: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-05-11 23:48:26 UTC)
loading tasks  2.1s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 100%
Total 2.2s
```

First of all, what does the error mean? What method "replace" is it talking about? Secondly, is there any way to have the `aliases.js` file be an object, rather than a group of strings? Returning an object, especially a nested one, would let me organize my tasks better.