# Log Grunt Command-Line Output to Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, gruntjs, npm

Is there a simple way to log the command-line output of a `grunt` task to the browser? By "log" I mean take the input &/or output of the command line and display it in a browser. I know I can write a whole big application to do this, but is there a `grunt` plugin or anything that already does it?

The reason I am asking is because I am asking [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599300/can-the-aliases-js-file-return-an-object-in-load-grunt-config) on this site that requires me to show some `grunt` tasks and their output. However, there is more than 1 file and, while not overly long files, they're overly long for a StackOverflow question. I'm thinking I can either upload the files to StackExchange and let answerers download them, or create a JSFiddle. I'm pretty much asking how I should create that JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look on Grunt website : http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.log

grunt.log.debug('watch');

Comment: Is that a legacy thing, @Kuldeep? The link at the top is broken & on grunt's GitHub page there is a "grunt-legacy-log" repo but no other related repos. If it isn't legacy, how do I specify which browser tab/window to log to?

Comment: @trysis link is working fine http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.log 

You need to add in grunt.js

Comment: Yes, I meant the link at the top of that linked page. Where it says "see the log lib source for more information", the link in that sentence is a link to `grunt`'s original `log` repo on GitHub, which does not exist anymore. This, along with the only `grunt` repo related to logging having "legacy" in the name (`grunt-log-legacy`) worries me.

Comment: @trysis - Surprisingly, That link(https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/log.js) is broken but i believe its not legacy.